# PowerBI Matrix Visual Conditional Formatting for date

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

Hope you can help

I have Matrix on my visual for a PowerBI dashboard as pre requirement, and said matrix has dates

I need to have the most recent date highlight in a different colour, and the problem is conditional formatting setting in the Matrix visual itself seem to only be accepting values and not dates

I was wondering if there is a way around it

[image: This is what it looks like]

Comment: does this answer your question [Highlight the max value in a chart /visual](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Highlight-the-max-value-in-a-chart-visual/td-p/2739213)